# Force of hydrogen nucleus on an electron

Tags: quantum-mechanics, forces

It is known classical mechanics doesn't works to describe atoms mechanics. I'm studying Coulomb's law, i.e:

$$F=\frac{k\,q_1q_2}{r_{12}{^2}}$$

that all of you know. I wonder if it is possible to calculate, using quantum mechanics, the force of the hydrogen nucleus (the proton) in the one electron. Just some help and links would be useful.

Comment: It is always worth mentioning the canonical transformation of the 2-body central force problem in these contexts. We generally introduce classical orbits in terms of a heavy central body and a light satellite and assume the primary is effectively stationary. Then we may mention the combined motion, but the mathematical details—i.e. the canonical transformation—are rarely worked out until later. But a proper treatment of the hydrogen atom starts with that transformation just as a proper treatment of Newtonian orbital motion does, so that the usual solution give the behavior of *both bodies*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hydrogen atom is well-studied problem in quantum mechanics. Using the Schrödinger equation, you can derive its wavefunction in spherical coordinates
$$ \psi_{n\ell m}(r,\vartheta,\varphi) = \sqrt {{\left (  \frac{2}{n a^*_0} \right )}^3 \frac{(n-\ell-1)!}{2n(n+\ell)!}} e^{- \rho / 2} \rho^{\ell} L_{n-\ell-1}^{2\ell+1}(\rho) Y_{\ell}^{m}(\vartheta, \varphi ).$$

This is the general form of the wavefunction. It's quite overwhelming. For the ground state ($n=1$, $\ell = 0$, $m=0$), we get the wavefunction

$$ \psi_{100} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}a_0^{3/2}}e^{-r/a_0}.$$

If you compute the product $\psi_{100}^*\psi_{100} = \psi_{100}^2$, this gives you the **probability distribution function** of the electron in the ground state. The issue with quantum mechanics is that the electron could be anywhere. We can only speak in terms of the probability of the electron's position measurements. We can say that the expectation value $\left< r \right>$ (sort of like an average) of the electron's position is

$$ \left< r \right> = \int_0^\pi\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^\infty \psi_{100}^*\psi_{100}r\cdot r^2\sin\theta drd\phi d\theta = \frac{3}{2}a_0, $$

where $a_0$ is the Bohr radius. This tells us that we expect the average of our measurements of the electron's position to converge to this value if we make many measurements.

Ehrenfast's theorem indicates that quantum mechanical expectation values follow classical equations. For Newton's second law

$$ \left<F\right> = \frac{d}{dt}\left<p\right> = \left<\frac{\partial V}{\partial r}\right> $$

and potential $$ V = \frac{e}{4\pi\epsilon_0 r},$$ we see that the force is $$ \left<\frac{dV}{dr}\right> = \left<\frac{-e^2}{4\pi\epsilon_0 r^2}\right>.$$

Therefore you must take the expectation value of $\frac{dV}{dr}$ to obtain the average magnitude of Coulomb force:

$$ \int_0^\pi\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^\infty \psi_{100}^*\psi_{100}\left(\frac{-e^2}{4\pi\epsilon_0r^2}\right) \cdot r^2\sin\theta drd\phi d\theta $$ $$ = \frac{-e^2}{\epsilon_0} \cdot \frac{1}{\pi a_0^3} \cdot \frac{a_0}{2}$$

$$ \rightarrow \left<F\right> = \frac{d}{dt}\left<p\right> = \frac{1}{2\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{-e^2}{a_0^2}.$$

Comment: @EmilioPisanty that is correct. See my edited answer.

Comment: That's less wrong, for sure. However, your current version is an accurate calculation of the average *magnitude* of the force, but if you want to do the average force itself (which is the only meaningful quantity as regard the Ehrenfest theorem) you need to include the vector character of the force; which will then produce a vanishing expectation value that's consistent with the fact that $\frac{d}{dt}⟨p⟩=0$ for all stationary states.

Comment: Cool, thanks. So different a results in qm and classical mechanics Isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the electron in a hydrogen atom doesn't have a position. It is delocalised over the atom. Since it doesn't have a position we don't have an $r$ to put into the Coulomb force equation.

The way to approach this is to use the potential $V(r)$ rather than the force. The force is then related to the potential by:

$$ F = -\frac{dV}{dr} $$

and the Coulomb potential is:

$$ V(r) = -\frac{k q_1 q_2}{r} $$

We can use this this to calculate the binding energy of the electron, and it comes out to be $13.6$ eV for the ground state of the hydrogen atom. So while we can't define a force in the classical sense, we can say that we need to do $13.6$ eV of work to pull the electron out of the hydrogen atom.